# document.getElementById in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

When I use `document.getElementById` in Internet Explorer I get this error:

```
Mensaje: El objeto no acepta esta propiedad o método
```

---

Translation:

```
Object does not support this property or method
```

---

and the execution stops

Html:

```
  <div id="contenedor">
  ...
  </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
  contenedor = document.getElementById("contenedor");
```

This works ok in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Google Translation: `Message: Object does not support this property or method`

Comment: Could you post ,your HTML code and more JS.Looks like,ID property for your element is not defined.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp

Comment: Have you created a local variable with name 'document'?

Comment: I hate to sound smart, but the JS in question doesn't support the function you're calling of it.  Maybe the object is null or undefined or maybe the function name is wrong.  Do you have any specific code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's simply `document.getElementById('someid')` that gives you this message, may be  placing your script at the bottom of the HMTL (right before the closing </body> tag) will help.

if you want to be shure the element is loaded before you assign it to a variable, use

```
window.onload = function(){
 contenedor = document.getElementById("contenedor");
};
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a misfeature in some(?) versions of IE where it defines global constants for every id value in the document. So when you write `contenedor = document.getElementById("contenedor")` — notice that it uses the div's name for the variable — it sees you're trying to set that global variable and complains that you can't. What you should do is declare a new variable instead of setting a global: `var contenedor = document.getElementById("contenedor")`

Comment: exactly what i was thinking ... `var` was missing

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your javascript is executing before DOM is ready.  Many javascript libraries include a mechanism for adding an event when DOM is ready, otherwise, one can use the body `onload` event.

You can try to put your javascript at the bottom of your document, but this is no guarantee that the code won't be executed before the page has loaded sufficiently to allow the browser to build the DOM tree.  You're much better off either using a framework with the `ready` or `domready` event (like mootools or jquery), OR using the body `onload` event as mentioned.

Example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var initPage = function() {
    // do stuff
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initPage();">
 <!-- page content -->
</body>
</html>
```